# How do I access Windows credentials from Java?

Tags: java, windows, security, single-sign-on

How do I (or can I?) retrieve the cached credentials for the currently logged-in Windows user in Java? I want to reuse these credentials in some other GSS-API calls. Specifically, I'm answering an SPNEGO challenge from IIS.

Thanks.

Comment: Answered in many questions. Below link will help you. > http://webmoli.com/2009/08/29/single-sign-on-in-java-platform/

Answer (score 10):

assuming you are using JAVA 5:

```
com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem NTSystem = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem();
System.out.println(NTSystem.getName());
```

[here is some info on the subject](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jaas/spec/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If IIS has Integrated Windows Authentication turned on, then you can still access the protected page by using the http://spnego.sourceforge.net/api/net/sourceforge/spnego/SpnegoHttpURLConnection.html class. This open source project's "credential delegation" tutorial also uses the SpnegoHttpURLConnection class.