# find out which user on the workstation started the program

Tags: java, swing

I want my application to figure which user have started it (the application). I will need it to send a mail to this user.

Can it be done in java?

thanks.

Comment: maybe this thread will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126684/how-do-i-access-windows-credentials-from-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would `System.getProperty("user.name")` be good enough for you, or do you need more?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have little knowledge in java. No need to get angry

Comment: You might need the full email adress or similar.  You did not say if you knew the domain name.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.name")` is easy to fake, just start your program from the commandline with `java -Duser.name="Chuck Norris" YourMainClass`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann this might actually be a feature if the only purpose for this is to send a mail.

Answer (score 2):

yup, you can use [NTSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/NTSystem.html)